# Dropdown options not populating with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to take some JSON and fill the options of dropdown menu.I am using Materialize a front end css framework which I think may be the root of the problem here. I say this because if I do it with the default browser dropdown it works exactly as I expect, but not with their (Materialize's) dropdown. I do have to init the dropdown when the page loads, so maybe the solution is I have to re-init it, but I do not know how to do that.

This is the html where the form is:

```
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <form class="col s12">                                         <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select ng-options="Country for Country in countries" ng-model="selCountry" ng-change="onChange('sel')">
                                <option value="" disabled>Select Indicator</option>
                            </select>

                        <label>Indicators</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="search_targets" type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="onChange('txt')">
                            <label for="search_targets">Search Targets</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12" style="
                        padding-left: 11.250px;
                        padding-right: 11.250px;
                        margin top:5vh;
                        ">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-field="id">Name</th>
                                    <th data-field="name">Score</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="item in records | orderBy:'Name':reverse | filter:selCountry | filter:searchText | limitTo: 10">
                                    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.Country}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is all of the JS I have, including the initialization of the dropdown @ the bottom:

```
(function($){


  angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var records;
    $scope.selCountry = '';
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').success(function(dt) {
      //window.alert(angular.toJson(dt));

      $scope.countries = [];
      $scope.records = dt.records;
      dt.records.forEach(function(o) {
        var c = o.Country;
        if ($scope.countries.indexOf(c) == -1)
          $scope.countries.push(c);
      });
      $scope.total = $scope.countries.length;
      ready();
    });

    $scope.matches = 0;

    $scope.onChange = function(src) {
      if (src === 'txt') {
        $scope.selCountry = '';
        $scope.search = $scope.searchText;
      } else {
        $scope.searchText = '';
        $scope.search = $scope.selCountry;
      }
      search($scope.search);
    };

  });
    $(function(){

    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();

  }); // end of document ready

    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
    $('select').material_select();
  });

})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

If the solution is to re-initialize the dropdown after the JSON is pulled, I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Where is your code making the AJAX request and populating the `select`?

Comment: Updated OP. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success callback, you must use `$scope.$apply` to apply scope modifications since `$http` is asynchronous. Then did you check what `dt` contains with `console.log(dt)`?

Comment: I mean I know what it contains. Like I was saying it works when I use it with the default browser dropdown. I tried `$scope.$apply` @ the end of the success call with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can reinitialize or update your select element by simply calling (as the same way you init)

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Note: You should call this statement on your success callback.